# Css-Grid / Flexbox aside and main not growing 100%

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I am creating a css-grid / flexbox template and it's all working as it should.

It has a header, aside, main and footer.

I just need the asign and main row to stretch so it takes the whole page minus the header and footer height.

I want to do this without having to use the "vh"

Here is the full current code:

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      
      body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 30% auto;
        grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
        grid-template-areas: "header header"
                             "sidebar main"
                             "footer footer"
      }

      header,
      aside,
      main,
      footer {
        padding: 16px;
        text-align: center;
      }

      header {
        background: purple;
        grid-area: header;
      }

      aside {
        background: blue;
        grid-area: sidebar;
      }

      main {
        background: green;
        grid-area: main;
      }

      footer {
        background: orange;
        grid-area: footer;
      }
```

How can I get the asign and main to auto stretch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:root{}` for that and `calc()` with variables to calculate the height. Sorry for re-coding your attempt, but I think it was better to start from zero to show you a new approach.

### Try the following snippet

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;padding: 0;margin: 0}
      
:root{
  --nav-height: 80px;
  --footer-height: 80px;
}
.grid-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
  height:calc(100vh - var(--nav-height) - var(--footer-height));
 }
.grid-item{
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
}
.nav{
  width:100%;
  height:var(--nav-height);
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
}
footer{
  width:100%;
  height:var(--footer-height);
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  <div class="nav">nav content</div>
  
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">body content one</div>
    <div class="grid-item">body content two</div>
  </div>
  
  <footer>footer content</footer>
 
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it the correct browser height, the view height (vh) property would be required.

You could alternatively use a fixed pixel height, or make it relative to the width for a specific aspect ratio, but neither of these would be responsive to 100% browser height.

Is there any reason you don't want to use vh?

Comment: Basically, 100% would auto grow but if I wanted to make aside and main stretch it I would have to manually calculate the vh minus header and footer height so I couldn't just do height: 100vh ... it would be maybe 90vh or something else..and I would have to change the vh everytime the header and footer grows too unless I want a scrollbar on the body

Comment: I think the easiest way to resolve that issue would be to set a designated height for your header and footer of say 50px and then use `height: calc(100vh - 100px);` for your main and aside divs and then it would fill the browser screen.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it strictly with flex-box would be to wrap both the aside and main in a div, and set flex property of the div to 1

```
<div class="container">
  <aside>aside</aside>
  <main>main</main>
</div>


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
```

but in order for that to work you would probably have to make the entire body a flex-box

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: I want to use mainly css-grid if at all possible.